# How to set a different interval value for each instance of a class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, setinterval

I have created some simple CSS flip cards and used setInterval to have them flip every 2 seconds.

```
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $('.flip-card').toggleClass('flip-card-flipped'); 
    }, 2000);
```

That works fine, but every card flips at the same time and I would like to have them flip one after the other. So I have been trying to use the .each function but the cards do not flip at all when I use .each.

```
    $(".flip-card").each(function(i, obj) 
    {
        setInterval(function()
        {
            obj.toggleClass('flip-card-flipped');

        },(i * 1000) + 2000);
    });
```

In this example, the flip animation takes one second, so the above code attempts to get the index of the class and multiply it by 1000 to get seconds to offset the interval by. so the first card will flip after (0 * 1000) + 2000, the next one will be (1 * 1000) + 2000 and so on, i.e. 2s, 3s, 4s....

Comment: please state your problem, too. I guess it is that your time intervals are wrong, right?

Comment: your intervals don't seem to be what you want, because the interval should be 2s for all cards. What you want instead is an offset, no?

Comment: @ChristianFritz " I would like to have them flip one after the other.", "the flip animation takes one second, so the above code attempts to get the index of the class and multiply it by 1000 to get seconds to offset the interval by".

Comment: I understood that part. But you haven't yet told us what isn't working with the code you've got so far. You are only saying "have had no success".

Comment: Ok I get you, they are not flipping at all with the .each code.

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell it is useful to have your developer tools open (*in the browser*) so you can see in the console errors that will hint what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me from reading the documentation, https://api.jquery.com/each/, how to use the `obj` argument to the `.each` function. In their examples they seem to recommend using `this` instead.

In addition it seems that you want an offset, rather than increasing the interval for latter cards. The interval, as you said, should be 2s for all cards. The only difference should be when they start their flipping cycles if I understand correctly. If so then you want an offset.

```
$(".flip-card").each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(() => 
        setInterval(() => $(this).toggleClass('flip-card-flipped'), 2000),
        i * 1000
    );
});
```

Comment: That works! it was the this instead of obj that fixed it, thanks so much.

Comment: As the name implies, `element` is the actual DOM element. So you can do `$(element)`. You can see this in the last [example](https://api.jquery.com/each/#example-2)